# MATLAB Database fetch() for WRDS Compustat taking too long

Tags: sql, matlab, fetch, wrds-compusat, wrds

I am connecting MATLAB to the Wharton Research Data Services COMPUSTAT database and am running a simple query

```
WRDS_Connect

setdbprefs('FetchInBatches','yes')
query = exec(WRDS, ['select gvkey from COMP.FUNDA where fyear = 2000 order by gvkey asc']);
result = fetch(query);
result.data
```

WRDS_Connect simply establishes a connection to WRDS server using JDBC drivers and

```
WRDS = database(instance, username, password, serverAddress);
```

The query is not too big and gives me 27000 rows of data. However it takes too long. Profiling shows that it takes about 5 minutes for these 27000 rows. 
I want to actually make more extensive queries but it should not take so long.

Is there anything I can do to speed things up? I've attached a screenshot of the profiling. [image: Profiling Screenshot]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to not sort with sql but do it in matlab after you imported the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PhD acount or above you can change approach a little bit.

I developed an API that lets you download datasets from WRDS unix servers. It's **easy** to use and **faster**.

Check it out on https://github.com/okomarov/wrds and let me know if you have **problems**.

```
wrds_install
w = wrds('username');
w.sas2csv('COMP.FUNDA');
```

The data will be saved in `.\data\COMP.FUNDA.zip`.

You can then:

1. unzip the table
2. import it with `readtable()`
3. apply selction/filters in Matlab

Comment: Hello, @Oleg, I want to use your package  shown in the link to connect to wrds in matlab, but everytime I run  wrds_install; and w = wrds('username','password'),  my matlab (2015Ra) in laptop collapes immediately. I do not know the reason.

Comment: @Shine Can you please submit an issue on github giving as many details as possible to rerproduce the issue (OS, code example, if you get something printed in the command window before the crash, the crash report by the OS)?